kivy shows blank screen
I am a beginner in kivy. i tried a basic programe but when running it i only get a blank black window.
I named my python file as try.py and the kv file as first.kv
The python file is:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass
class TheLabApp(App):
    pass
TheLabApp().run()

the kivy file contains:
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "hello"
        size: 400,400

I got the following message from interpreter:
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\hp\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-05-24_10.txt[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4425'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000'> 
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.00 - Build 10.18.10.4425'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop

but when i run the python file i only get a plain blank screen (with no widgets) enter image description
both python file and kv file are in same directory
please help.........

Your kv file is not getting loaded. You must either load the file using Builder. Something like:
Builder.load_file('first.kv')

Or by using the auto load capabilities of Kivy (see the documentation) by changing the kv file name to thelab.kv.
